# C++ multiple definition despite ifndef when used in multiple files

Tags: c++, c, redis, linker-errors

**I just wanted to clarify - redismodule.h is not written by me but is from the GitHub repo for Redis**

For some background I'm writing a C++ Redis module and I keep getting linking errors on `redismodule.h` when trying to use it in multiple files. I can confirm that there is an `ifndef` in their `redismodule.h` header. I primarily just use their header for definitions and the only implementation is for the `RedisModule_OnLoad` method in `foo.cpp`.

This is the error I'm getting:

> /usr/bin/ld: RedisFunc/bar.cpp.o:/redismodule.h:183: multiple
>   definition of 'RedisModule_Alloc'; 
>   RedisFunc/foo.cpp.o:/redismodule.h:183: first defined here

I get this error for lines 183 to 306 and I get this for the following files in my project:

- foo.cpp
- bar.cpp

This is the structure of my project:

**RedisFunc**

- foo.cpp
- bar.cpp

**Redis source**

- redismodule.h

**foo.cpp includes:**

foo.h

**foo.h includes:**

redismodule.h

**bar.cpp includes:**

bar.h

**bar.h includes:**

redismodule.h

My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
include_directories(src)
add_executable(redis-server
        src/adlist.c
        ...
        src/t_stream.c
        )

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99 -pedantic -DREDIS_STATIC= -Wall -W -Wno-missing-field-initializers")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -g -ggdb -rdynamic")

include_directories(RedisFunc)

configure_file(redis.conf redis.conf COPYONLY)

add_library(RedisFunc MODULE
        RedisFunc/foo.cpp
        RedisFunc/bar.cpp
        )
```

The redismodule.h file can be viewed here:

https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/5.0/src/redismodule.h

Comment: People who are down voting the post please reply and say what is wrong with the question

Comment: What code is at or around redismodule.h line 183?

Comment: @MikeVine https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/1b7407fadf8b3790b519f27253af0923da2aeccc/src/redismodule.h#L183

180 #define REDISMODULE_API_FUNC(x) (*x)
181
182
183 void *REDISMODULE_API_FUNC(RedisModule_Alloc)(size_t bytes);
184 void *REDISMODULE_API_FUNC(RedisModule_Realloc)(void *ptr, size_t bytes);
185 void REDISMODULE_API_FUNC(RedisModule_Free)(void *ptr);

Comment: @MikeVine just want to clarify that `redismodule.h` wasn't written by me

Comment: Looking at redismodule.h it cannot be used in multiple c/c++ files at the same time. You should only include it in one of them, and then forward declare anything else you need in the other c/c++ files.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right @MikeVine I'll try that

Comment: Building on Mike Vine response - I think you can also define "REDISMODULE_CORE" so that you can still include in all the c/c++ files (for the definitions) but have the implementation in a single place.

Comment: Thank you @MikeVine and tarkmeper that was my issues and it's working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CANNOT use redismodule.h directly. It has some definition NOT declaration of functions. So if you include it directly, you'll get multiple definition problem.

Instead, you should split this .h file into a .h file and a .cpp file. declare these functions in .h file, and define them in the .cpp file.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right, I'll try that. Sorry, I'm so new to C/C++ and learning as I go

Comment: You guys were right, that was the problem. Thanks again. So it seems like they obfuscated their definitions with a macro that made me miss it. It's working now